# Getting S_412_PRECONDITION_FAILED=Invalid arguments error in Linkedin share api

Tags: linkedin-api

When try to update status with link in linkedin api i'm getting this error frequently.

**Example Link**: 
http://www.world-grain.com/articles/news_home/World_Grain_News/2016/06/General_Mills_files_patent_on.aspx?ID={30B4213B-4E10-4AF6-9B56-0D5614D7AFD3}&cck=1

If i remove the { and } from the link it get posted. Even in linkedin site itself its not working.

Help me if anyone know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error and the reason was that I didn't send values for all the keys in request's body. For example: "content" parameter in linkedin's request body is a dictionary with 4 keys:

- title
- description
- submitted-url
- submitted-image-url

I had no image url so I didn't set the key "submitted-image-url" at all. The solution was to set the value to empty string "".

I wonder why linkedin can't parse dictionary if it doesn't have all the keys but that's the way it works.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes the same i too tried its working...Sorry to update here. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to URL encode the braces in your link:

```
http://www.world-grain.com/articles/news_home/World_Grain_News/2016/06/General_Mills_files_patent_on.aspx?ID%3D%7B30B4213B-4E10-4AF6-9B56-0D5614D7AFD3%7D&cck=1
```

I ran into the same error when I attempted to pass a URL with spaces. It published successfully after URL encoding the spaces (`%20`).