# LinkedIn API Publish on network (S_412_PRECONDITION_FAILED=Invalid arguments)

Tags: linkedin-api, laravel-5.3

When I try to publish a link on my own LinkedIn profile via the LinkedIn API, I get this error:

[LinkedIn return error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ARnr.png)

```
Request Error: Invalid arguments: {S_412_PRECONDITION_FAILED=Invalid arguments}
```

My request:

```
$li = new LinkedIn([
    'api_key' => env('LINKEDIN_KEY'),
    'api_secret' => env('LINKEDIN_SECRET'),
    'callback_url' => env('LINKEDIN_REDIRECT_URI')
]);

$li->setAccessToken('my_token');

return $li->post('/people/~/shares', [
    'content' => [
        'title' => 'This is an example of title',
        'description' => 'This is a text with less 256 caracters.',
        'submitted-url' => 'https://www.google.fr/',
    ],
    'comment' => 'This is comment with less 700 caracters.',
    'visibility' => [
        'code' => 'anyone'
    ]
]);
```

I use the official API of LinkedIn (linkedinapi/linkedin).

Comment: Did you check following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806237/getting-s-412-precondition-failed-invalid-arguments-error-in-linkedin-share-api

Comment: Yes, I have already read this post...